# Select2 not rendering palceholder tag when used with multiple

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, html-select

I'm trying to get a basic multi select to work with select2 but the placeholder is missing.

HTML:

```
<select id="country" multiple data-placeholder="Select a country">
    <option>Spain</option>
    <option>France</option>
    <option>Germany</option>
</select>
```

jQuery (select2 initialization):

```
$('#country').select2({
    placeholder: $this.data('placeholder'),
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    dropdownParent: $this.parent()
});
```

So the end result is that there is no `.select2-selection__placeholder` element rendered at all, like it is when you remove the `multiple` attribute from the select element (then the placeholder works as expected). Apart from that the multiple select works fine.

I've tried a lot of different solutions but none have worked, mostly due to in most cases the placeholder is rendered just not visible or similar.

Select2 version is **4.0.8**

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code and there should be errors in your console - you cannot simply access `#country` as `$this` considering you're not in an event, you're calling `.select2()` like a function. You also shouldn't have to set the `placeholder` configuration option at all as it should pull from `data-placeholder` automatically.